# HTML element appear outside wrapper element using div's

Tags: css, asp.net, html, webforms

I am working on visual studio express 2013 and create a default project based on webform with default template as shown in link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPWzRd

For some reason Header & footer elements appear our their main wrapper as it is show in the codepen example. I tried to play around with few css properties but it breaks the design.

```
<header>
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><a href="./"> logo here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Test">Test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

How can ii fix this so that Logo and menu items show inside the Header Wrapper (basically inside the red box) and same for the footer section

Comment: Because they are floating.... You already have the clearfix there just use it at just before the end of the header.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use in CSS

`display: inline-block;`

instead of

`float: left;`

Full example:

`.float-left {
   display: inline-block;
}`

It's because style `float` makes element "invisible" for parent. Style `display: inline-block` acts similar to `float` but is "visible".

Comment: width display inline-block you can't positiong insid elements to left and right

Answer (score 1):

when you have to element inside in other div and two div's are floating after that you need to add clear.

forked example

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mymMMz

```
<header>
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><a href="./"> logo here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Test">Test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
           <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </header>


.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

or add `overflow hidden` to `.header-wrapper`

Comment: What about footer section